# Store menu only has Launch Windows App Certification Kit

Tags: visual-studio

I have a Silverlight phone 8.1 project. Under the store menu I only see Launch Windows App Certification Kit. I have installed all the SDKs and everything else is ready to submit my app. How can I submit my app since I don't have an app package? I am running VS 2013 with all the latest updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can interact with the Store by using the `Store menu` in Visual Studio. In Visual Studio Ultimate 2013, open the `Project` menu, and then choose `Store`. The Store menu appears only if you’re working on a Store project or solution. In Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows, the Store menu appears directly on the menu bar. The first three commands on the menu are always available, but the availability of the other commands depends upon where you are in the development process.

If you want to modify the `store` menu, go to `Tools` -> `Customise`. There, you can select/unselect options.

Comment: The only thing in the store menu is "Launch Windows app Certification Kit".